# Stripe get product id for one-time payments

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to get the product id for one-time payments, but I am unable find ANY webhook event that would give me the id of the product purchased.

I know that for subscriptions, `invoice.paid` event provides the product id, but one-time payments do not produce invoice.

I have read some suggestions such as appending product id to metadata of checkout session and listening for `checkout.session.completed`, but I am not sure whether that is a reliable source for the confirmation of the payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Checkout for one-time payment, then yes `checkout.session.completed` is the event you want. However you will need to [Retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the Checkout Session using its Id. You can expand its [line_items.data.price.product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price-product).